# Python : issue of memory with the function map

Tags: python, memory

I do not understand why the function `map` does not free memory after 
its execution even if I do not store the result in memory. I have tried 
to do a garbage collector, used objgraph but I don't see any object store in the memory.

Basic use of `map` :

```
map(lambda x:x*x,range(10**8))
```

[image: htop screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot, the memory is full. I ran the code on 
ubuntu 16.04, with python 2.7.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: How do I interpret the screenshot? Its opera, and related to your python program how? It may be better to post a line showing memory usage here in the question.

Comment: I don´t see any python process in the list.

Comment: `range` creates a large list. It goes out of scope and its freed at the python level, but the process still has that memory. It may end up on swap but its going to stay in the process.

Comment: Yes, but how can I free this memory ?

Comment: Pretty sure you are seeing [this](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm)

Comment: Use `xrange` on Python2 to avoid allocating an entire list before applying the lambda-operation. Python3's `range` is `xrange`.

Comment: xrange does not change the issue. Thanks juanpa for the link it gives some interesting elements. I trie to understand memory allocation in python to debug scientific computing in my work.